# ordering queries based on most upvotes

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to order my query based on the number of upvotes but I can't  figure out how to do it. It seems way too complex!
( btw am I over-complicating things?)

so here is my **models.py**

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    FAVORITE = 'F'
    LIKE = 'L'
    UP_VOTE = 'U'
    DOWN_VOTE = 'D'
    FOLLOW = 'W'
    REPORT = 'R'
    ACTIVITY_TYPES = (
        (FAVORITE, 'Favorite'),
        (LIKE, 'Like'),
        (UP_VOTE, 'Up Vote'),
        (DOWN_VOTE, 'Down Vote'),
        (FOLLOW, 'Follow'),
        (REPORT, 'Report')
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    activity_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ACTIVITY_TYPES)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # Below the mandatory fields for generic relation
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()


class Entry(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(default='')
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    time_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class QuestionManager(models.Manager):
    def by_topic(self, topic):
        ...
    def by_recent(self):
        ...
    def by_upvote_count(self):
        return self.all().order_by('-upvotes')[:5]\
        .select_related('created_by','created_by__userprofile')\
        .prefetch_related('question_comments','question_comments__reply',)


class Question(Entry):

    objects = models.Manager()
    get = QuestionManager()

    activities = GenericRelation(Activity, related_query_name='questions')

    def calculate_votes(self, type):
        return self.activities.filter(activity_type=type).count()

    up_votes = property(calculate_votes, 'U')
    down_votes = property(calculate_votes, 'D')
```

so, what I'm trying to do is to get by_upvote_count to return the top 5 upvoted items.

I found the **Count()** method of the **django.db.models** but could get it to work with my set up, I want to do something like this:

```
Question.objects.all().annotate(q = Count(activities__activity_type='U')).order_by('-q')
```

but obviously this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
Model.objects.filter(activity_type='U').annotate(q_count=Count('activity_type')).order_by('-q_count')[:5]
```

Comment: that would sort them by all the activities, but I want to sort them just by the Upvotes, downvotes, likes or ...

Comment: so, your answer kind of works, but it's not exactly what I want.
if you change Count('activity_type') to Count('activities__activity_type) and filter(activity_type='U') to filter(activities__activity_type='U'), but this returns all posts that have been upvoted and excludes the ones that don't have an upvote yet.

My answer below includes both types, and that is what I'm looking for.

Thanks for your help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after reading a bunch of articles and some questions in stackoverflow, I finally found a working answer, here it goes:

```
from django.db.models import Case,When
Question.objects.all()\
.annotate(upvotes=Count(
    Case(
        When(activities__activity_type='U', then=1)
    ), distinct=True
)).order_by('-upvotes')[:5]
```

Using [Case, and When](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) you can do conditionals in your queries.